# sfdx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, cli

Unable to get past this error when Creating the Hello World Lightning Web Component

[image]

I checked the path variable as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163795/sfdx-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Do you have salesforce CLI installed ? To check try typing sfdx --version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue when I added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin in the Environment Variable Path

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're on a Windows computer. If the restart doesn't solve the issue, I'd check whether you allowed the installer to `Set PATH to Salesforce CLI` ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If You're sure it's installed, restart your computer and try again. installation changes may nor always immediately take effect, and so restarting can make sure all changes are applied.,