# CLI installation sfdx is not recognized

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am trying to get VS Code and SF CLI to work but after the installation of both I am getting the "sfdx is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..." when I attempt to test my CLI installation.

I've looked at other threads on here ([sfdx is not recognized...](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163795/sfdx-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?rq=1) but they've confused me.

I've looked and my CLI appears to have been installed in c:\Program Files\sfdx\

I noticed that link I included mentioned a c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\ folder which I do not have.

Can anybody give some input on what to do here ? I've started and restarted my VS Code client.

I'd really appreciate any help I could get.